# Trying to install mysql-devel on CentOS

Tags: mysql, centos

I am trying to install mysql-devel on my CentOS system and it's failing with some weird dependency issue.  Here is the result I get when I try to install from the command line.

```
$ sudo yum install mysql-devel
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
 * base: mirror.steadfast.net
 * epel: epel.mirror.freedomvoice.com
 * extras: linux.mirrors.es.net
 * updates: ftp.linux.ncsu.edu
Setting up Install Process
...
...
--> Finished Dependency Resolution
Error: Package: mysql-5.1.69-1.el6_4.x86_64 (updates)
       Requires: libmysqlclient_r.so.16()(64bit)
       Available: mysql-libs-5.1.66-2.el6_3.x86_64 (base)
           libmysqlclient_r.so.16()(64bit)
       Available: mysql-libs-5.1.67-1.el6_3.x86_64 (updates)
           libmysqlclient_r.so.16()(64bit)
       Available: mysql-libs-5.1.69-1.el6_4.x86_64 (updates)
           libmysqlclient_r.so.16()(64bit)
       Installed: mysql-libs-5.5.32-1.el6.remi.x86_64 (@remi)
           Not found
Error: Package: mysql-devel-5.1.69-1.el6_4.x86_64 (updates)
       Requires: libmysqlclient_r.so.16()(64bit)
       Available: mysql-libs-5.1.66-2.el6_3.x86_64 (base)
           libmysqlclient_r.so.16()(64bit)
       Available: mysql-libs-5.1.67-1.el6_3.x86_64 (updates)
           libmysqlclient_r.so.16()(64bit)
       Available: mysql-libs-5.1.69-1.el6_4.x86_64 (updates)
           libmysqlclient_r.so.16()(64bit)
       Installed: mysql-libs-5.5.32-1.el6.remi.x86_64 (@remi)
           Not found
Error: Package: mysql-5.1.69-1.el6_4.x86_64 (updates)
       Requires: libmysqlclient_r.so.16(libmysqlclient_16)(64bit)
       Available: mysql-libs-5.1.66-2.el6_3.x86_64 (base)
           libmysqlclient_r.so.16(libmysqlclient_16)(64bit)
       Available: mysql-libs-5.1.67-1.el6_3.x86_64 (updates)
           libmysqlclient_r.so.16(libmysqlclient_16)(64bit)
       Available: mysql-libs-5.1.69-1.el6_4.x86_64 (updates)
           libmysqlclient_r.so.16(libmysqlclient_16)(64bit)
       Installed: mysql-libs-5.5.32-1.el6.remi.x86_64 (@remi)
           Not found
```

Any ideas on how to address this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i fixed this by uninstalling and re-installing mysql.